# Pygame cannnot be imported

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

I've installed pygame using the command `pip install pygame`. When I enter my python console and so import pygame it gives me `ImportError: No module named pygame` and then tried installing with `sudo apt install python-pygame` but I am still facing the same issue. I finally resulted to cloning from https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame and build then installing and I'm still getting the import error. Is there any other way available that i could install pygame?

Comment: Are you using Python3? If so, you should probably be using `pip3`.

Comment: No I am using python2

Comment: This post on askubuntu might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/399824/how-to-install-pygame

Comment: I did and tried out the solution given but I still get ImportError. Anytime I reinstall pygame it says **Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that running `pip install pygame` without the **sudo** would actually install everything from scratch and could now be imported if you run `import pygame` from the python console. I don't know the reason for that funny behavior but it works for me now.